# Can't use key_digest instead of password_digest for has_secure_password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt

I am trying to use bcrpyt with has_secure_password but instead of password_digest attribute, I am using key_digest. as the documentation of has_secure_password allows us to use any XXX_digest.( https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password )

I am using it as a key will be generated from the system and the user doesn't need to enter any password. but for this example, I am just trying the key to be encrpted and saved in the database. If I change key to password, it works. I am not sure why key is not working

I am getting `NoMethodError in Users#new` and `undefined method "key" for #<User:0x000000000d0beb38>`

### users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  private
  ## Strong Parameters
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :key_digest, :key)
  end
end
```

### users/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Sign Up</h1>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :key %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :key %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Sign Up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

### 20210605052011_create_users.rb

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :key_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

### routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'static#home'

  get 'static/home'
  get 'static/faq'
  get 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'
  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
  get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your User model, haven't field `key`, so error show.  Change your code as below to save with hash password!

Edit your `app/views/users/new.html.erb` to:

```
<h1>Sign Up</h1>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Sign Up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

With `app/controllers/users_controller.rb`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

private
  ## Strong Parameters
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
  end
end
```

Last, don't forget install bcrypt gem and set this content `app/models/user.rb` to:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  alias_attribute :password_digest, :key_digest
end
```

Any things will fine! : D

Comment: Lol isn't key_digest supposed to store the encrpted hashes of the original key just like we don't store the actual password in password_digest but the encrypted password in password_digest and in the view we take only password. So, if we do like you mentioned, then there will be no encryption or use of bcrypt / has_secure_password as I am storing the actual key in in key_digest from new.html.erb?

Comment: Edited, for save to key_digest with hash password!